# Unable to detect mouseenter on appended div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a file like this for my html:

```
<div id="append">
     <div class="sample"> Sample Text 1 </div>
</div>
```

In my jquery file, this is what i do to append the rest of the divisions,

```
$.each([ 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ], function( index, value ) {
      $('#append').append("<div class="sample"> Sample Text "+ value.toString() + " </div>");
});
```

The problem that I am having is that the appended divisions (Sample Text 2 and more) cannot detect a mouse enter event. I tested it by doing this:

```
$("div.sample").mouseenter(function(){
    alert("Mouse Enter Event Detected");
});
```

I only get the alert when hovering over the first `div.sample`. The appended divisions does not seem to detect it.

What can I do to detect mouseover event for the appended divisions?

Comment: use `.on()` delegate the event like `$('#append').on('mouseenter','.sample'.function(){})`

Comment: You need live event. Right now all events attached after page init don't have event listener on them. Like guradio says you ca use `.on()` and event listener will be created automatic when new element is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following script for this

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "div.sample", function(){
    alert("Mouse Enter Event Detected");
});
```

Comment: better to mark as duplicate so OP can delete the question

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your suggestion, will remember this in future.